# Tmux in multiple Terminal.app windows

Tags: macos, tmux

I'm just trying out Tmux so that I can avoid ssh'ing into the same host over and over again. I like the panes and windows that tmux offers, but here are my sticking points:

1. I have to ssh into a separate server (server1), authenticate with Duo, and then ssh from that server to my final destination (server2). It's a pain to authenticate with Duo, so I'd rather be able to do it once and then multiplex from server1.
2. My setup has 2 monitors and I would rather have 2 separate Terminal.app windows. If I make one long window, it gets cut off between the monitors.
3. I can't find a way to move a tmux window into a new Terminal.app window. I could manually open another Terminal window, ssh into server1, start tmux, and attach/new-session -t into a group, but that defeats point #1.

Is there a way to do what I want? Here are some things that are close:

- http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.terminal-emulators.tmux.user/3447
- gist.github.com/chakrit/5004006

Here's a graphical ideal:

[image: tmux-2-windows]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try iTerm with tmux integration since you're on OS X - it might give you what you're after.

> When you run "tmux -CC", a new tmux session is created. An iTerm2
>   window opens and it acts like a normal iTerm2 window. The difference
>   is that when iTerm2 quits or the ssh session is lost, tmux keeps
>   running. You can return to the host you were ssh'ed into and run "tmux
>   -CC attach" and the iTerm2 windows will reopen in the same state they were in before.

Comment: This seems promising, but when I try it out I get this issue:
"Unsupported tmux option", as documented in this issue: https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible/issues/24
tmux 2.1

Comment: This does work for some hosts but not others. Thanks!